# Using postgres to replace csv files (pandas to load data)

Tags: postgresql, pandas

I have been saving files as .csv for over a year now and connecting those files to Tableau Desktop for visualization for some end-users (who use Tableau Reader to view the data).

I think I settled on migrating to postgreSQL and I will be using the pandas library to_sql to fill it up.

- I get 9 different files each day and I process each of them (I currently consolidate them into monthly files in .csv.bz2 format) by adding columns, calculations, replacing information, etc.
- I create two massive csv files using pd.concat and pd.merge out of those
  processed files which Tableau is connected to. These files are literally overwritten every day when new data is added which is time consuming

Is it okay to still do my file joins and concatenation with pandas and export the output data to postgres? This will be my first time using a real database and I am more comfortable with pandas compared to learning SQL syntax and creating views or tables. I just want to avoid overwriting the same csv files over and over (and some other csv problems I run into).

Comment: 1 problem per question, at the moment this is too broad

Comment: Narrowed it down to my major question and the thing I am most hesitant about doing (because when I read about databases I see so much about normalized tables and such and my implementation will certainly not be so clean initially.. I am basically going to use it as a big flat file to store data and connect Tableau to)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry too much about normalization. A properly normalized database will usually be more efficient and easier to handle than an non-normalized. On the other hand, if you have non-normalized csv data you dump into a database, your import functions will be a lot more complicated if you do a proper normalization. I think I would recommend you to make one step at the time. Start up with just loading the processed csv-files into postgres. I am pretty sure all processing following that will be a lot easier and quicker than doing it using csv-files (just make sure you set up the right indexes). When you start to get used to using the database, you can start to do more processing there.

Just remember, one thing a database is really good at is to pick out the subset of data you want to work on. Try as much as possible to avoid pulling out huge amount of data from the database when you only intend to work on a subset of it.

Comment: That is good to hear. I have had to do a lot of workarounds to be able to read a certain range of dates from csv files, and I am not able to specify a certain ID that I am interested in so querying will be helpful.

Does pandas to_sql take care of the datatypes for me or do I construct the tables in postgres first and assign datatypes?